# How to redirect to an external url with Selenium, and come back?

Tags: facebook, perl, redirect, selenium, oauth

I am working in perl with Selenium RC, server version 2.19.0-b09 and I cannot figure out whether it is even possible to redirect to an external URL and come back to my application. I am trying to test Facebook OAuth in my application, which means I have to go to Facebook and come back to my app.

```
use Test::WWW::Selenium::Catalyst 'MyApp', -selenium_args => 'injectProxyMode -trustAllSSLCertificates -debug -log /home/me/browserlog.txt -firefoxProfileTemplate /home/me/.mozilla/firefox/SeleniumUser.default/';

my $selenium = Test::WWW::Selenium::Catalyst->start({
    browser => '*chrome',
});
```

The reason I think this is possible at all is because a custom Firefox profile and the -injectProxyMode, *chrome browser and -trustAllSSLCertificates options enable me to post to and see all the redirects in my debug log, but my Remote Control window always disappears after the redirects. I can see the PROXY URL to which Facebook is trying to send me back, e.g., a URL on my own base domain. But it looks like there is no window for it to return to. In multiWindow mode I am left with my application in a Firefox window. In singleWindow mode my tests just end and all the windows close.

I have tried both -singleWindow and -multiWindow mode. I have gotten the list of windows after I make my post to https://www.facebook.com:443/login.php... and before all the redirects. I see a single window that is never available to select_window, and it always disappears on the second iteration if I run get_all_window_names in in a while loop: a window with a name like "_e_0RWG".

So, how could I conceivably do what I am trying to accomplish with Selenium? It seems so near and yet so far.